# A recurrent Markov Chain implies its k-step version is also recurrent?

Tags: probability, markov-chain-montecarlo, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I am curious about whether a Markov Chain $X_n$ is recurrent implies that for any $k > 0$, $X_{kn}$ is also recurrent.

Here are my observations. If $X_n$ is transient, $X_{kn}$ must be transient by verifying the definition. In addition, if the state space is finite, $X_n$ and $X_{kn}$ both are positive recurrent.

In my understanding, the recurrence means that we can always pick a sequence $\{n_t\}$ s.t. $X_{n_t} = i$ given $X_0 = i$. However, there is no guarantee that there exists $n_{t_j}$ s.t. $k | n_{t_j}$. I also did some numerical simulations e.g. 1-D random walk and the result indicates that $X_{kn}$ is also recurrent.

Comment: I think periodicity can give you a counterexample. For example, with a 1D random walk starting at zero, and with $k=2$, the $k$-step chain will never reach odd states.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Yes, i think in this case the chain becomes reducible. But the state 0 seems still recurrent? Could we have some example that the state i is recurrent and then in the k-step chain it is transient?

Comment: If the chain is aperiodic, then the $k$-fold chain is also recurrent.